# why jquery can't do submit function?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I can't use jquery for submit the form?!
I want to submit the form without button submit type, but when i click on ok for confirmation submit doesn't work.

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Product
<div class="well">
    <h3>
        <strong>@Model.Name</strong>
    </h3>
    <button id="@Model.ProductID" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">
        Use
    </button>
    <span class="lead">
        <br />
        @Model.NumberLine
    </span>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToUserProducts", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString != null ? $"{ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Path}{ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString}" : ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.ToString() }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = Model.ProductID, role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProductID)
    }
</div>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("button#@Model.ProductID").click(function () {
                        var temp = Number($("#userNumberLimit").val()) + @(Convert.ToInt32(Model.NumberLine));
                        if (temp <= 1000000)
                        {
                            if (confirm("Are You Sure?\nThis will be evaluated in your daily limitation."))
                            {
                                $("form#@Model.ProductID").submit();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert('You have reached daily limitation.');
                        }
                    });
                });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the c# model value inside the javascript variable before using it in the script.

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("button#"+model.ProductID).click(function () {
                        var temp = Number($("#userNumberLimit").val()) + @(Convert.ToInt32(Model.NumberLine));
                        if (temp <= 1000000)
                        {
                            if (confirm("Are You Sure?\nThis will be evaluated in your daily limitation."))
                            {
                                $("form#"+model.ProductID).submit();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert('You have reached daily limitation.');
                        }
                    });
                });
</script>
```

Comment: @user11948300 Does this answer your query?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery could not find the element with a selector: `form#123`.

From jquery document:

#### id selector

> Description: Selects a single element with the given id attribute.
>
> version added: 1.0jQuery( "#id" )
>   id: An ID to search for, specified via the id attribute of an element.
>
> For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function document.getElementById(), which is extremely efficient. When another selector is attached to the id selector, such as h2#pageTitle, jQuery performs an **additional** check before identifying the element as a match.

For more info about jQuqery ID selector, please reference:

https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

---

For the selector `$('form#123')`:

JQuery will first find the element with Id: `123`. Then it will check if it is a `form`.

Now before the `form`, there is another element with Id: `123`, and it is a button. jQuery don't think that the result matches your selector.

```html
<button id="123" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">
        Use
</button>
<form id="123">
    ...
</form>
```

So jQuery can not find your form.

Chang your form Id from `Model.ProductID` to `"myForm" + Model.ProductID`.

Which means you need to change your code to:

```cs
new { id = "myform" + Model.ProductID, role = "form" }
```

```
 $("form#myform@Model.ProductID").submit();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#ProductID").click(function () {
                        var temp = Number($("#userNumberLimit").val()) + @(Convert.ToInt32(Model.NumberLine));
                        if (temp <= 1000000)
                        {
                            if (confirm("Are You Sure?\nThis will be evaluated in your daily limitation."))
                            {
                                $("#@Model.ProductID").submit();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert('You have reached daily limitation.');
                        }
                    });
                });
</script>
```